# App engine default Django version change

Tags: google-app-engine, django-templates

Since app engine 1.4.2 was released, I am getting warnings like this in my production logs:

> You are using the default Django
>   version (0.96). The default Django
>   version will change in an App Engine
>   release in the near future. Please
>   call use_library() to explicitly
>   select a Django version. For more
>   information see
>   http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django

This occurs on every handler where I use a Django template - via the following:

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
```

I'd like to upgrade to 1.2, however the following links don't seem very clear on exactly how to do this (or whether it works at all):

- http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django
- http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1758
- http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4489
- http://www.mediacrafters.org/post/django11-on-appengine

The common thread is to insert this:

```
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.2')
```

However, in what file(s) should this be inserted:

1. Just in appengine_config.py?
2. In every .py file which does `from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template`?
3. In every .py file in the project?
4. In 1 and (2 or 3) above, and also add `import appengine_config` to those files?
5. In 3 or 4, and also add wrappers around built-in functions like appstats, remote api, datastore admin, etc?
6. Something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

As described by Nick in the comments of systempuntoout's answer, I inserted this `use_library()` code [from here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django) in every handler that imports django (either directly or via `google.appengine.ext.webapp.template` or even just `django.utils.simplejson`):

```
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.2')
```

As suggested by Nick, this was made easier by first refactoring to minimise the number of handlers referenced by app.yaml (ie, closer to [scenario 1 described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025921/is-there-a-performance-gain-from-defining-routes-in-app-yaml-versus-one-large-map)).

However, I have the appstats builtin configured, and if I first went to /_ah/appstats after an upload, then I would get this error:

> <'google.appengine.dist._library.UnacceptableVersionError'>:
>   django 1.2 was requested, but
>   0.96.4.None is already in use

I was able to fix this by also including the `use_library()` code in `appengine_config.py`.

I noticed that by inserting a call to `use_library()` in `appengine_config.py`, then it was no longer necessary in all of my handlers. In particular the ones which import `google.appengine.ext.webapp.template` don't need it, because importing `webapp.template` loads `appengine_config.py`. The appstats UI imports `webapp.template`, which is why this fixed that problem.

However, I had some handlers (eg json services) which don't import `webapp.template`, but do import `django.utils.simplejson`. These handlers still require a direct call to `use_library()`. Otherwise, if those handlers are called first on a new instance, the  `UnacceptableVersionError` occurs. Although I am using `appengine_config.py` to configure appstats, meaning `appengine_config.py` gets called to instrument all requests, it gets called too late in the page lifecycle to properly configure the correct version of Django.

This all appeared to work okay at first, but then I discovered a backwards incompatibility between the new Django 1.2 and the old Django 0.96 which I'd been using. My project structure is like this:

```
root
+- admin
|  +- page_admin.html
+- page_base.html
```

With Django 0.96, having the following in page_admin.html worked fine:

```
{% extends "../page_base.html" %}
```

With Django 1.2, I got this error:

> TemplateDoesNotExist: ../page_base.html

The change in Django 1.2 seems to be that by default, Django doesn't allow loading templates which are above the original template's directory.

A workaround for this is described [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/61aa9f7b282889a2/d0165683ddd0c82b), but this approach couldn't work for me, as it requires the templates to be in a templates subdirectory.

The solution to this is to set up a `settings.py` file, set the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting to the project root directory, and then change the `extends` tag to just reference `"page_base.html"`, as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957089/render-to-response-gives-templatedoesnotexist). However, I ran into two problems trying to do this.

I was using the [recommended code](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/templates.html) to render my template, ie:

```
template_values = { ... }
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'page_admin.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

The first problem is that `template.render()` overrides the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting, to set it to the directory of the template being rendered. The solution to this is the following code:

```
template_values = { ... }
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'page_admin.html')
template_file = open(path) 
compiled_template = template.Template(template_file.read()) 
template_file.close()  
self.response.out.write(compiled_template.render(template.Context(template_values)))
```

One downside of this approach though is that `template.render()` caches the compiled templates, whereas this code doesn't (although that wouldn't be hard to add).

To configure the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting, I added a `settings.py` to my project:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__) 
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (PROJECT_ROOT,)
```

And then in all of my handlers, before the `use_library()` code, I set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` [as described here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django):

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
```

The second problem was that this didn't work - the settings file wasn't getting loaded, and so the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` was empty.

Django settings are loaded from the specified `settings.py` lazily, the first time they are accessed. The problem is that importing `webapp.template` calls `django.conf.settings.configure()` to attempt to set up some settings. Therefore if `webapp.template` is imported before any settings are accessed, then `settings.py` is never loaded (as the settings accessor finds that settings already exist, and doesn't attempt to load any more).

The solution to this is to force an access to the settings, to load the `settings.py`, before `webapp.template` is imported. Then when `webapp.template` is later imported, its call to `django.conf.settings.configure()` is ignored. I therefore changed the Django version setup code in all of my handlers (and `appengine_config.py`) to the following:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings' 

from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.2')

from django.conf import settings
_ = settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS
```

In practise, I actually put all of the above code in a file called `setup_django_version.py`, and then import that from all of my handlers, rather than duplicating these 6 lines of code everywhere.

I then updated my `page_admin.html` template to include this (ie specify `page_base.html` relative to the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting):

```
{% extends "page_base.html" %}
```

And that fixed the problem with rendering the admin page.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your work figuring this out. I had the same issue when I changed my Django version to 1.2 and you saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Awesome answer. Answers the question plus all possible follow up questions.

Comment: Something that tripped me up was that after adding my TEMPLATE_DIRS variable, it still didn't seem to work. It turns out it was because I was still using the custom app engine template loader. Once I switched to django's template loader, it started working.

Comment: It would be really useful if the App Engine documentation linked to this.

Comment: it's insane that it needs to be this complicated.

Comment: Thank you. We need much more documentation on GAE :-( we need you :-)

Answer (score 17):

As of GAE 1.5.0, there's much simpler, though momentarily under-documented, way of specifying which version of Django templates you want to use.

In `appengine_config.py`, include the line

```
webapp_django_version = '1.2'
```

That's it.

No more need for `use_library()`.

Comment: The `webapp_django_version` setting actually existed before 1.5.0, but it still has some problems. From every handler which imports django (either directory or indirectly), you need to make sure you have 'from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template' first, or else it will fail. Also in older versions before 1.5.0, using this technique would still have the problem with ignoring settings.py which I mentioned. It looks like this has been fixed in 1.5.0 though. So this now looks like an effective technique, as long as you import the template library everywhere, which is not hard :)

Comment: Note that this does not work if using the Python 2.7 runtime. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6536723/201828.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django) you are properly linking, you should just add this function at the beginning of your `main.py` script handler .

Comment: @systempuntoout: I don't have a main.py script handler - my app.yaml has about 20 handlers pointing at different .py files, each of which have around 1-10 handler classes in them. Some of those use templates, and some do not (eg services and tasks).

Comment: @Nick: I thought there was no specific recommendation on whether you should have app.yaml point to N .py files with handlers in them, or have app.yaml point to 1 .py file, with N handlers in it?

Comment: @Nick: Eg see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025921/is-there-a-performance-gain-from-defining-routes-in-app-yaml-versus-one-large-map

Comment: @Saxon There isn't, but you're not really gaining anything by separating it out to such a degree, and creating a great deal of pain for yourself in doing so.

Comment: @Nick: So do I need to call `use_library()` from every handler which app.yaml invokes? In that case, yes it is a bit painful :) Otherwise, it's been pretty painless so far, and does a nice job of keeping the functional areas of the site separate :) In theory I could cut it back to 2 (eg one for most of the site and one for the `login: admin` urls), but that would feel a bit like I was combining unrelated functions. Maybe around 4 would be a nicer compromise, eg admin, services, tasks, pages (in addition to the built-ins like appstats, remote api, etc).

Comment: @Saxon You need to call it - or import a module that calls it - from every handler that uses Django, either directly or transitively. Personally, I would recommend using one handler for each more or less independent component of your app - 'main' and 'admin' are natural divisions.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I refactored my project a bit, and then put `use_library()` in all of my handlers. I found though that if I went to /_ah/appstats first after an upload, then to my site, it would fail with `<'google.appengine.dist._library.UnacceptableVersionError'>: django 1.2 was requested, but 0.96.4.None is already in use`. I seem to have fixed that by also putting `use_library()` in appengine_config.py.

Comment: Thanks Nick for the discussion, and thanks systempuntoout for your answer which prompted the discussion :) I ran into some more issues running Django 1.2, so I've written up a separate answer with what I had to do to get it to work.

Comment: I see this error in my dev server log files even though I do not use or import django in any handlers. Is there a way to know which handler is triggering this warning?

Answer (score 2):

One thing I'd like to mention that the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries#Django) doesn't make clear: if you use [`google.appengine.ext.deferred`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred) and have `use_library` in your `main.py`, then when the deferred task is *executed* it will NOT load `main.py` and if you are unlucky enough to have a deferred task as your first request to an instance, it will bork the instance (causing it to throw `UnacceptableVersionError` when your `main.py` attempts to call `use_library` on a later request). I think if you add `use_libary` to [`appengine_config.py`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appengineconfig) it will work with `deferred` as well, but we ended up switching to regular task queues (which handlers ARE routed through `main.py`) to avoid this problem.