# How to move logic from appengine_config.py file on Google App Engine (Python)?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have used file **appengine_config.py** in root of my project directory. This file contains next code:

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext.appstats import recording
from gae.sessions import SessionMiddleware
import gae.webapp

COOKIE_KEY = 'my_private_key_used_for_site_%s' % os.environ['APPLICATION_ID']

def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):
    app = SessionMiddleware(app, cookie_key=COOKIE_KEY, cookie_only_threshold=0)
    app = recording.appstats_wsgi_middleware(app)
    return app
```

This code helps me enable cookies and App Stats for my application.

I need to delete this file, and move this logic to file into separate package. I need to clear project root directory. It is possible?

Comment: I have found next question where people says that this is impossible to delete this file. Link to question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557079/what-is-appengine-config-py

Comment: Why do you need to delete it?

Comment: The webapp framework expects this file to reside in the root directory.

Answer (score -1):

Try deploying an empty appengine_config.py file.