# How is the template directory set in App Engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I'm currently keeping my templates in `/projectdir/static/html/`. I've begun to have enough of them that I've created a subdirectory: `/projectdir/static/html/tag_request/`. If I want to have a template in `/tag_request/` inherit from one in `/html/` how do I do it?

I've read that with django `{% extends base.html %}` should be written relative to `/projectdir/templates/` or wherever `TEMPLATE_DIRS` points. How do I set `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in appengine (or do I have to put my templates in `/projectdir/templates/`)?

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be storing program data (Eg, templates) in a static directory. If you've marked it as static in app.yaml, it won't be accessible from your code once it's uploaded.

Comment: Thanks. So the best solution would be to just to move my templates to '/projectdir/templates/' and adjust my code accordingly (since it shouldn't be in static anyway)? BTW What do you mean by "accessible from your code"?  The app deploys OK. What am I loosing when I put templates in static?

Comment: I was just going in to implement the change mentioned in my last comment and I noticed that I never reference /html/ in my app.yaml. It only get's accessed through main.py. Is that why I don't have any issues so far?

Comment: It's only an issue if you list `/static` as a `static_dir` in app.yaml, which seemed likely given the name. Static files are served directly by the frontends without any involvement from your app, so they're not accessible by code.

Comment: Ahhh. My app.yaml only lists subdirectories of static (e.g. `static/css`, `static/js`).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to depend on which version of Django you are using.

If you're using 0.96, then just this works:

```
{% extends ../base.html %}
```

If you're using 1.2, then in theory you need to create a settings.py which sets the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` to `/projectdir/static/html/`, and then use this:

```
{% extends base.html %}
```

However I found a couple of issues with this - my solution is described here:

[App engine default Django version change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994913/app-engine-default-django-version-change)

Comment: Thanks. I won't be able to get back to this until Thursday. But I will be back.