# How to use use_library('django','1.2')

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm learning developing in Google App Engine.

This is one of the code from the tutorial, http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingwebapp.html

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('Hello, webapp World!')

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/', MainPage)],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've almost identical code. I sometime get warning:

> WARNING  2011-06-30 13:10:44,443 **init**.py:851] You are using the default Django version (0.96). The default Django version will change in an App Engine release in the near future. Please call use_library() to explicitly select a Django version. For more information see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django

Can anyone please re factor the above code with use_library(). I'm not sure how to start and where to use use_library and what to do with webapp.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

The above code should not require you to call use_library directly.

If you create a new file in the root directory of your application named `appengine_config.py` and add the following line to it:

```
# Make webapp.template use django 1.2
webapp_django_version = '1.2'
```

Comment: That's how I do it. For the curious, this causes a `use_library` to happen under the covers.

Answer (score 3):

try putting this code on top of your module :

```
import os
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.2')
```

Comment: @Amol Add these lines in the top of the file you pasted before importing the webapp, this way you can skip the appengine_config.py.

Comment: The `appengine_config` approach is preferable (and it's a one-liner). Problems with the `use_library()` approach happen on those infrequent moments when a request hits a new instance of your app and gets fielded by some bit of code that you don't have direct control over. Without specifying the django version in `appengine_config.py`, if that code imports webapp, that instance of the app will get locked on 0.96.

Comment: @Dave I think this happened to my app (id classifiedsmarket) getting unaccetableversionerrors some time today, then importing the library to all modules and now finally upgrading to use the file `appengine_config.py'

Comment: But many of the configurables (including the django version line) aren't supported in the Python 2.7 version of GAE.  Try changing your app.yaml to read "runtime: python27" and having the 1-liner in appengine_config.py will fail to get read.  See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appengineconfig.html for details (in particular the line that reads "webapp (For advanced users. Not available in Python 2.7)")

Answer (score 1):

In the current version this is even simpler as third-party libraries are now specified in app.yaml

```
libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.2"
```

You can also use webapp2 that includes Django’s templating engine.

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp2 import template
```