# Comparing appengine database values in Django

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-templates

Hi i have an appengine application with the following db.Model:

```
class Cinema(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    address = db.StringProperty()
    distance = db.IntegerProperty()
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(RunningUser)
```

When I fill my template everythings works fine:

```
            {% for cinema in cinemas %}
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="/images/cinema.png"></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="...">
                            <h2>{{cinema.name}}</h2>
                        </a>
                        {{cinema.address}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {% if cinema.distance > 10000 %}
                            <p>red</p>
                        {% endif %}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

Except the if statement. Python raises a `TemplateSyntaxError: 'if' statement improperly formatted exception`. According to Django it should be fine. So what is wrong with these three lines?

```
{% if cinema.distance > 10000 %}
    <p>red</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Make sure that you are referring to the same version of django documentation which you use on appengine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Version 0.96 (whish is the standard version of appengine) does not support the greater operator.

Comment: Appengine has django 1.2. You can change the version with `use_library` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994913/app-engine-default-django-version-change). Though my personal opinion is that django is not suited for appengine. I would recommend `Kay Framework` or `Flask` over Django. I think Django is just a huge overhead and cause headaches when used on appengine.

Comment: Thanks for this info. I am using django with appengine and python. Especially for my purposes (i am only using the template system) it produces no overhead and is very good for my prototype webapps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
{% if cinema.distance > 10000 %}
    <p>red</p>
{% endif %}
```

from: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#id3

Comment: I tried all variations with brackets... none of it worked... Or did I miss a detail?

Comment: the solution above MUST work! if you are still getting the error, it might be somewhere else in your template! double check all if tags! and confirm if you are closing the block(endif)!

Comment: I think the problem is that I am using the standard django version of appengine (which is 0.96). It seems that this version doesn't support the > operator.

Comment: Completely right!  if you check the version1.0 docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#if you can see that there is no > operator! too bad!! so you can return a Boolean variable from your view to your template!