# TemplateDoesNotExist on python app-engine django 1.2 while template rendering absolute paths

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-templates

Due to App Engine warning

> You are using the default Django version (0.96). The default Django version will change in an App Engine release in the near future. Please call use_library() to explicitly select a Django version. For more information see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django

I have added two lines of code to top of main.py

```
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library("django", "1.2")
```

This code totally broke my app raising this error

```
File "/home/adel/Software/google_appengine/lib/django_1_2/django/template/loader.py", line 138, in find_template
raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
TemplateDoesNotExist: /home/adel/Workspace/jeeneo/site/Common/templates/en_US/template.html
```

I have been googling and found developers with similar problem about relative path no longer supported in Django, in my case I used absolute path and my code is structured this way

```
site/
    Frontpage/
        template/en_US/index.html
        index.py
    Events/
        template/en_US/event.html
        template/en_US/create.html
        event.py
        create.py
    Common/
        template/en_US/template.html
        template.py
```

Every class inherent Template class like this

```
from Common import Template
class Event(Template):
    def get(self):
```

Then call

```
self.render(__file__, "event.html")
```

To render HTML file, the render function have this inside

```
def render(self, path, html):
    self.base = self.get_base()
    email = None
    if self.user:
        self.auth_url = users.create_logout_url("/")
        email = self.user.email
    else:
        self.auth_url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)

    self.template.update({
        "base": self.base,
        "user": self.user,
        "lang": self.lang,
        "template_html" : os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates/%s/template.html" % self.lang),
        "email": email,
        "auth_url": self.auth_url
    })

    html = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path), "templates/%s/%s" % (self.lang, html))
    self.template.update(self.data)
    self.response.out.write(template.render(html, self.template))
```

And the html file (event.html) has this code

```
{% extends template_html %}
```

I have two solutions in my mind, perhaps restructure everything and make all templates in one folder, or have local install of Django 0.96 on App Engine... but I am pretty sure there must be an easier solution.

Comment: Please include _all_ the relevant code (eg, the whole Template class), not just one-line snippets.

Comment: Also, is the path that it claims the template doesn't exist on valid?

Comment: @Nick I have attached full render function.

Comment: @Nick adel@adel-laptop:~/Software/google_appengine$ file /home/adel/Workspace/jeeneo/site/Common/templates/en_US/template.html
/home/adel/Workspace/jeeneo/site/Common/templates/en_US/template.html: HTML document text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some similar issues, with some fixes which I describe here:

[App engine default Django version change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994913/app-engine-default-django-version-change)

When you use app engine's `template.render` it sets the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` to the directory of the template you are rendering. The `extends` tag in Django 1.2 checks that the templates being included are inside the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` directory. If they are in a parent (or sibling) directory then it fails.

The solution to this that I found was to not use app engine's `template.render`, and instead write my own using Django's Template class. I then also had to set `TEMPLATE_DIRS` to the root of my project directory.

This is going from my memory of how it was in 1.4.2, when I first looked into this - the behaviour might have changed since (although my workarounds still work fine).

Comment: Thank you, I will try your solution in few hours and report back.